Scrapy script does not start spiders
I have created a new scrapy projects with a spider (multiple to be added). The spider works without any issues if started with
scrapy crawl myspider
However, when I try to run the scraper from a custom script, it does not start. I have broken down the script to a bare minimum that does not work:
from scrapy.spiderloader import SpiderLoader
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.project import get_project_settings
from scrapy.utils.log import configure_logging
from twisted.internet import reactor

settings = get_project_settings()
configure_logging(settings)
runner = CrawlerRunner(settings)
spider_loader = SpiderLoader.from_settings(settings)
for spider in spider_loader.list():
    print(f"Adding Spider: {spider}")
    runner.crawl(spider_loader.load(spider))

d = runner.join()
d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
reactor.run()

The output of the script is:
$ python3 minimal.py
Adding Spider: myspider
2024-12-06 14:52:02 [scrapy.addons] INFO: Enabled addons:
[]

The script than hangs, and no additional messages from the spider are printed. I confirmed that no network traffic related to crawling is observed. The code is very close to the documentation, so I am little bit clueless on what the problem could be and where to look.
Edit:
This is a minimal crawler that does not run:
import scrapy


class GoogleSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = "google"
    allowed_domains = ["google.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.google.com"]

    def parse(self, response):
        pass

# Scrapy settings for fwscraper project
#
# For simplicity, this file contains only settings considered important or
# commonly used. You can find more settings consulting the documentation:
#
#     https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html
#     https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
#     https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html

BOT_NAME = "fwscraper"

SPIDER_MODULES = ["fwscraper.spiders"]
NEWSPIDER_MODULE = "fwscraper.spiders"


# Crawl responsibly by identifying yourself (and your website) on the user-agent
#USER_AGENT = "fwscraper (+http://www.yourdomain.com)"

# Obey robots.txt rules
ROBOTSTXT_OBEY = True

# Configure maximum concurrent requests performed by Scrapy (default: 16)
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS = 32

# Configure a delay for requests for the same website (default: 0)
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/settings.html#download-delay
# See also autothrottle settings and docs
#DOWNLOAD_DELAY = 3
# The download delay setting will honor only one of:
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_DOMAIN = 16
#CONCURRENT_REQUESTS_PER_IP = 16

# Disable cookies (enabled by default)
#COOKIES_ENABLED = False

# Disable Telnet Console (enabled by default)
#TELNETCONSOLE_ENABLED = False

# Override the default request headers:
#DEFAULT_REQUEST_HEADERS = {
#    "Accept": "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8",
#    "Accept-Language": "en",
#}

# Enable or disable spider middlewares
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spider-middleware.html
#SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    "fwscraper.middlewares.FwscraperSpiderMiddleware": 543,
#}

# Enable or disable downloader middlewares
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html
#DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
#    "fwscraper.middlewares.FwscraperDownloaderMiddleware": 543,
#}

# Enable or disable extensions
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/extensions.html
#EXTENSIONS = {
#    "scrapy.extensions.telnet.TelnetConsole": None,
#}

# Configure item pipelines
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/item-pipeline.html
#ITEM_PIPELINES = {
#    "fwscraper.pipelines.FwscraperPipeline": 300,
#}

# Enable and configure the AutoThrottle extension (disabled by default)
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/autothrottle.html
#AUTOTHROTTLE_ENABLED = True
# The initial download delay
#AUTOTHROTTLE_START_DELAY = 5
# The maximum download delay to be set in case of high latencies
#AUTOTHROTTLE_MAX_DELAY = 60
# The average number of requests Scrapy should be sending in parallel to
# each remote server
#AUTOTHROTTLE_TARGET_CONCURRENCY = 1.0
# Enable showing throttling stats for every response received:
#AUTOTHROTTLE_DEBUG = False

# Enable and configure HTTP caching (disabled by default)
# See https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#httpcache-middleware-settings
#HTTPCACHE_ENABLED = True
#HTTPCACHE_EXPIRATION_SECS = 0
#HTTPCACHE_DIR = "httpcache"
#HTTPCACHE_IGNORE_HTTP_CODES = []
#HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = "scrapy.extensions.httpcache.FilesystemCacheStorage"

# Set settings whose default value is deprecated to a future-proof value
TWISTED_REACTOR = "twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor"
FEED_EXPORT_ENCODING = "utf-8"


I was't able to reproduce Your issue with your code (tested on my test project with 2 spiders) code You provided - correctly loaded and executed all spiders in project.

A minimal reproducible example of the issue needs to also include the spider.

You are absolutely right. I'll edit the post to contain the spider. But in my tests it does not matter what spider I use.

After some more tries, I seem to have narrowed down the problem. If I replace "runner = CrawlerRunner(settings)" with "runner = CrawlerRunner()", everything seems to run.

Then you also need to include the settings (minimized, of course).

I added the settings.py. This is the standard unmodified from scrapy startproject

You requested a non-default reactor in your settings so you need to install it explicitly when using CrawlerRunner (this is mentioned in https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/asyncio.html#installing-the-asyncio-reactor). You also need to do it before importing twisted.internet.reactor as that installs the default reactor (this is mentioned in https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/asyncio.html#handling-a-pre-installed-reactor). A correct code example is shown in https://docs.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html#run-scrapy-from-a-script:
import scrapy
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerRunner
from scrapy.utils.reactor import install_reactor

install_reactor("twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor")
runner = CrawlerRunner()
d = runner.crawl(MySpider)

from twisted.internet import reactor

d.addBoth(lambda _: reactor.stop())
reactor.run()


twisted.internet.asyncioreactor.AsyncioSelectorReactor" most likely appeared "by default" from project template's settings.py https://github.com/scrapy/scrapy/blob/37be9da4e4d65c90b26197b7efafde0f213e56b0/scrapy/templates/project/module/settings.py.tmpl#L90-L91
